# How to find derivative of $u(x_1+rz_1,\cdots,x_n+rz)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $u\in C^2(U)$ be harmonic, $u:\bar{U}\subset \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$. $$\phi(r) := \int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(y) dS(y)= \int_{\partial B(x,1)} u(x+rz) dS(z)$$

How do I find $\phi'(R)$?

Do I first write:
$$u(x+rz)=u(x_1+rz_1,\cdots,x_n+rz_n)?$$

Then the derivative with respect to $r$, comes into $\phi$?

$$\phi'(r)=\int_{\partial B(x,1)} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} u(x_1+rz_1,\cdots,x_n+rz_n) dS(z)$$

Or have I already gone wrong?

I know the answer is $\int_{\partial B(0,1)} Du(x+rz)\cdot z dS(z)$ but can't obtain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$
\xi_j=x_j+rz_j
$$

$$
\phi'(r)=\int_{\partial B(x,1)}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_j}(\xi)\frac{\partial \xi_j}{\partial r}\mathbb{d}S(z)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \xi_j}{\partial r}=z_j
$$

$$
\phi'(r)=\int_{\partial B(x,1)}\sum_{j=1}^{N}z_j\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_j}(\xi)\mathbb{d}S(z)
$$

$\sum_{j=1}^{N}z_j\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi_j}(\xi)$, is the inner product of $z=(z_1,z_2,\dots,z_N)$ and $Du(x+rz)=(\frac{\partial u(\xi)}{\partial \xi_1},\frac{\partial u(\xi)}{\partial \xi_2},\dots,\frac{\partial u(\xi)}{\partial \xi_N})$. So we can write the above more compactly as

$$
\phi'(r)=\int_{\partial B(x,1)}z\cdot Du(x+rz)\mathbb{d}S(z)
$$

It looks like you had all the right ideas in going forward. I hope what I've done helps you understand.

Comment: Thank you very much, it certainly has!

Comment: Only one question really remains I guess, and that is, was I correct in thinking the very first step was:
$$\phi'(r) = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \phi(r)=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int u(x+rz) dS(z)=\int \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  u(x+rz) dS(z)$$

I.e. we are just pulling the derivative into the integral (is this the leibniz integral rule?)

Comment: @calculus Yes, I used the same trick.